# Why will my responsive nav not toggle class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am very new to coding and I'm working on a final project for class.
I'm attempting to make a responsive menu that utilizes HTML, CSS and JavaScript but for some reason the code is not working. When I click the hamburger menu, it does not toggle the "active" class.

I'm not sure why it won't work.
Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active')
  })
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-bars menu"></i>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#services">services</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">testimonials</a></li>
  </ul>


</nav>
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is in a media tag allowing the CSS to only work in screens under 768px. To learn more on the media tag take a look at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp. Here's your code but I removed the media tag:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-bars menu">Toggle menu</i>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#services">services</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#testimonials">testimonials</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of $(document).ready, have you tried $(window).load?

So instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
  })
});
```

Try:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active');
  })
});
```

Hope that helps.